# Flask and Gunicorn with Additional Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, gunicorn, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to build a Flask app with Gunicorn to serve concurrent requests. For what it's worth, the context is a bring-your-own-container Sagemaker application.

The issue is that I need the application to periodically check for updates. So I thought to implement a thread for this. Here is a minimal example of some Flask code with an update thread.

server.py

```
from flask import Flask
import time, threading

app = Flask(__name__)

message = True

def update():
  while True:
    message = not message
    time.sleep(10)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  global message
  return message

update_thread = threading.Thread(target=update)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  update_thread.start()
  app.run()
  update_thread.join()
```

I then launch with gunicorn:

`gunicorn -k gevent -b unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock -w 4 server:app`

Perhaps unsurprisingly the update thread doesn't start since the `__main__` section is never executed.

> **Question**: *How can one use an update thread (or similar construct) in a Flask app with Gunicorn?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this can be accomplished using `Flask-APScheduler` as follows:

`pip install flask_apscheduler`

server.py

```
from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import atexit

app = Flask(__name__)

message = True

def update():
  global message
  message = not message

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=update,trigger="interval",seconds=10)
scheduler.start()
# shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
atexit.register(scheduler.shutdown)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  global message
  return message

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Then launching as usual with 
`gunicorn -k gevent -b unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock -w 4 server:app`